# ngrx "No provider for ReducerManager" in monorepo

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, monorepo

I recently updated our monorepo project from Angular V10 to V12 and thus, ngrx from version 10.x to 12.2.0.

Unfortunatly, our own library components don't recognize the store anymore.

The application's main module looks something like this:

```html
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        LoggedInComponent,
    ],
    imports     : [
        StoreModule.forRoot({}),
        PortalModule,
        HeaderModule,
        ...
    ],
    bootstrap   : [LoggedInComponent],
})
export class FirstModule {
}
```

PortalModule lays in the same application and uses StoreModule.forFeature(...) successfully.

The HeaderModule is a module from the library which also uses StoreModule.forFeature(...) but this causes the following error:
[image: error description]

The setup worked before the update and I have no clue why it doesn't anymore. If I add another StoreModule.forRoot({}) in the library, the error is gone but it seems like the stores can't communicate anymore. It's almost as if there are two different versions of the ngrx store installed and the library uses another one than the application.

Comment: What if you dont import StoreModule in the sub modules at all? As I remember its only to be used for the sake of lazy loading because the providers on the top are registered to the submodules

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... Don't I need StoreModule.forFeature() in the Submodule in order to access the corresponding features and register new reducers?